# How to create Genmodel and model code from ecore programmatically using EMF API?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

are there any tutorials available for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'd be better to ask on the EMF newsgroup because I found this only because of a Google alert.  There's and ant task for doing this, EcoreGeneratorTask, so that would be a good place to look for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-dynamicemf/) might be a good starter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure wether this is still interesting, but in [this thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/513278/) a possible solution was described.